# how to counter dot dot slash attack?

Tags: php, .htaccess

How can I restrict the user into the root directory and not able to get access to the parent directory of the root.

I have EasyPHP installed and following I am considering as root:

```
http://127.0.0.1/projects/Web%20Developement/aureus/files/
```

I don't want user to able to move to the parent directory but when I add "dot dot slash" `../` at the end of above URL I can access "aureus" directory. How can I stop this by `.htaccess` or any other way?

Comment: This isn't an issue with real servers; the only reason you can do it here is because you are allowed to access aureus. If you went to `http://127.0.0.1/../` you would be blocked. Similarly, if the full path you posted was your actual root path, you wouldn't be able to get to `aureus`, because servers are smarter than that.

Comment: Wny not just set your DocumentRoot to the correct directory? (Presumably `/projects/Web%20Developement/aureus/files/`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do correctly with `.htaccess`. You'll need to edit the configuration for the domain in the main config file. When you go into your `httpd.conf` file or your included file for the virtual hosts you need to look for the [`DocumentRoot`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#documentroot) you're setting for the server. The web server only has access to what you grant it.

If you can access a folder you're trying to lock down via the web or a browser on another machine, you'll need to look at a variety of permissions settings depending on the OS you're running. You can restrict access to folders and prevent the users in Linux for example from seeing the files with `chmod`. In Windows (if that's what you're running) you would right-click on the folder, select `properties`, and change the permissions under the `security` tab.

Comment: @user2437432 sure thing. This question will likely be moved to another server.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the point of all this is, but if you simply don't want any `../` in your URLs, then you can try adding this to your htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.\./(.*)$ /$1$2 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: It does not help.Let me explain I want the user not to have access to parent directory.Can I do that in .htaccess?

Comment: That rule simply removes `../` from the url. So if someone were to try `example.com/any/../thing`, they'll be redirected to `example.com/anything`

Comment: @user2437432 if you want to deny access, then create an htaccess file in the parent directory with `Deny from all`, then an htaccess file in the `/file/` directory with `Allow from all`.

Answer (score 0):

I think rather than specifically try to stop the use of ../ in the url, you should have htaccess in folders you do not want people/bots/other to be in.

This

Options -Indexes

in a .htaccess file will stop directory listing in whatever folder the htaccess file is in. It'll serve a 403, but you can use htaccess to serve 404 or redirect based on what you need (other than "stop user to able to move to the parent directory" I'm not 100% sure what you want)

Cheers